# How to run Flex application after disable flash player in all browsers after 2020

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash, browser, adobe

I'm still supporting a couple of flex applications because migration is in progress, is there any option to enable the Flashplayer in the browsers to run flex applications? clients being using these applications regular basis. Please suggest how to continue the Flashplayer support for the next months.

Answer (score 0):

Below information, I found from official documents and from blogs for Microsoft browsers.

For enterprises seeking assistance with moving away from Adobe Flash Player, or needing continued support for line of business applications that may be dependent on it after 2020, Adobe is providing some [support options](https://theblog.adobe.com/update-for-enterprise-adobe-flash-player/).

To aid such customers, Microsoft Edge will allow Adobe Flash Player to load as a plug-in via the Internet Explorer mode feature. Inherently, Internet Explorer 11 will also allow this. Once you make the switch from Microsoft provided Adobe Flash Player, it will be treated as any other third-party plug-in and will not receive Customer Support from Microsoft.

References:

1. [UPDATE: Adobe Flash Player end of support on December 31, 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/update-adobe-flash-support)
2. [Update on Adobe Flash Player End of Support](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/04/update-adobe-flash-end-support/)
3. [The End of an Era – Next Steps for Adobe Flash](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/07/25/flash-on-windows-timeline/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to run Flex after 2020-01-12

Change computer time or modify a file in chrome.
More information can be found here

https://jclsn.medium.com/end-of-adobe-flash-player-520109caa05a